# Не получается сделать расшифровку шифра

Tags: java, криптография, шифрование

Есть код, который шифрует строку в соответствии со следующим заданием:
ТРАНСПОЗИЦИЯ С ФИКСИРОВАННЫМ ПЕРИОДОМ: В этом случае сообщение делится на группы символов длины d и к каждой группе применяется одна и та же перестановка. Эта перестановка является ключом; она может быть задана некоторой перестановкой первых d целых чисел. Таким образом, для d=5 в качестве перестановки можно взять: 23154. Это будет означать, что:m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9 m10...переходит в:m2 m3 m1 m5 m4 m7 m8 m6 m10 m9

Также мне необходимо производить расшифровку зашифрованной строки (Как я думаю, для расшифровки необходимо создать ключ, который в противоположность ключу шифрования будет возвращать все элементы на свои места)

Вот этот код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String phrase = "I want to walk my cat";
        final String phrase2 = "awn Iot  tkl awc aymt";
        int key = 34215;// ключ для замены элементов местами
        int key2 = decryptionkey(key); //ключ для расшифровки

        System.out.println("Шифр:");
        final String result = transposal(phrase, getArrayFromInt(key));
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("Расшифровка:");
        final String result2 = transposal(phrase2, getArrayFromInt(key2));
        System.out.println(result2);
    }

    private static int decryptionkey(int key){ // метод для расшифровки, который, по какой-то причине, не правильно создаёт ключ для расшифровки 
        String s = key+"";
        int [] mass = new int[s.length()];
        for (int i=mass.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            mass[i]=key%10;
            key=key/10;
        }
        for (int ss : mass){
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<mass.length;i++){ //я думаю проблема где-то в этом цикле, но так и не понял где
            int temp = mass[i];
            mass[i]=mass[mass[i]-1];
            mass[mass[i]-1]=temp; //по какой-то причине присваивается не то, что должно
        }
        String res="";
        for (int ss : mass){
            res+=ss;
        }
        int a = Integer.parseInt(res);
        return a;
    }

    private static List<Integer> getArrayFromInt(int key){
        final List<Integer> keyArray = new ArrayList();
        while (key>0){
            keyArray.add(key%10);
            key=key/10;
        }
        Collections.reverse(keyArray);
        return keyArray;
    }

    private static String transposal(String s, List<Integer> positions) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(getCharByPosition(s.toCharArray(), positions));
        return sb.toString().trim();
    }

    private static StringBuilder getCharByPosition(char[] charArray, List<Integer> position) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < charArray.length) {
            for (int pos : position) {
                final Character charByPosition = getCharByPosition(charArray, counter+pos-1);
                if (charByPosition != null) sb.append(charByPosition);
            }
            counter = counter + position.size();
        }
        return sb;
    }

    private static Character getCharByPosition(char[] charArray, int position){
        return charArray.length<=position ? null : charArray[position]; 
    }


}
```

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос/проблема?

Comment: @ Эникейщик, не получается расшифровать зашифрованное сообщение обратно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить ключ дешифровки нужно ключ шифрования зашифровать самим ключом шифрования

```
private static int decryptionkey(int key) {
  List<Integer> keyArr = getArrayFromInt(key);
  int[] resArr = new int[keyArr.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < keyArr.size(); i++)
    resArr[keyArr.get(i) - 1] = i + 1;

  int res = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < resArr.length; i++)
    res = res * 10 + resArr[i];
  return res;
}
```

Comment: В строке res = res * 10 + keyArr[i]; выдаёт ошибку, когда меняю её на строку res = res * 10 + keyArr.get(i);, ошибка вылезает в строке resArr[keyArr.get(i)] = i;

Comment: Почему-то всё равно выдаёт ошибку в строке resArr[keyArr.get(i)] = i;

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at Class3.decryptionkey(Class3.java:25) // эта ошибка относится к строке resArr[keyArr.get(i)] = i;      


at Class3.main(Class3.java:11) //эта ошибка возникает в методе main при вызове метода decryptionkey

Comment: @SemenovNilolay Исправил